# Link docker volume files to host filesystem on mac

Tags: macos, docker, docker-volume, docker-for-mac

For `docker-for-mac` is there a way to symlink or in any way get the files created by volumes (using `docker volume create`)  on the host system?

I can check the files using

`screen /Users/duvunuriz/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`

and

`docker run --rm -it -v /:/vm-root alpine ls -l /vm-root/var/lib/docker/volumes`

And similarly with this container I am able to backup the files.

But I want to get them on host filesystem, such that I can edit those files and they directly get reflected in the volume. Any workaround to symlink or get them via another container like above are also welcome.

Comment: You're using -v to mount your host files in your container. You can do the opposite - mount the container files onto the host `-v ~/container1:/var/log`. This will create a container1 directory on the host and you can see anything within the container's /var/log on there. Any changes in either would be automatically reflected in the other.

Comment: @StefanR I am looking for way to access files created by `docker volume create`. That example is just a way to view those volume files.